# Как загрузить в базу данных данные с cvs через League/csv?

Tags: php, laravel, csv

Парсю с `cvs` таблицы данные с помощью `legue/cvs`, дальше их надо загрузить в бд, застрял на этом этапе, не нашел как правильно это делать.

```
$csv  = Reader::createFromPath('test.csv', 'r');
$header = $csv->getHeader(); 
$records = $csv->getRecords(); 
Product::create($csv->toString());
```

Сама ошибка

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::create() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\OSPanel\domains\grand\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Traits\ForwardsCalls.php on line 23
```

Comment: ну ошибка же явно говорит что $csv->toString() возвращает объект, а должен быть массив на вход метода create. Смотрите что возвращает ваш toString и от этого уже решайте проблему

Comment: Что видно на первый взгляд: Вы парсите CSV и получаете строки в $records (предполагаю, что это массив), после чего создаёте ОДИН Product, может тут необходим цикл по элементам $recods в котором Вы будете создавать экземпляры Product?